# option from series of mySQL select queries dependent upon "if, if/else" PHP statement result

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to code PHP to perform a mysql SELECT query, to pull a roomprice value, if a condition is met based on input in a fifth table which stores the user input of the roomtype selected?

For example:

I have separate tables based on each type of room with prices for each date of that room type.

[image: tables]

If the user, in the HTML form, selects a DBL room for the ABC_2 tour starting 6-Feb (ABC_2 tour could have multiple start dates), would there be a way to code php to sort of option a query based on this user entered value posted to the reservation table under Roomtype1?

### PHP

```
if ($row['roomtype1']) = `SGL`  {
$tourquery = "SELECT SELECT sg.roomprice, r.totpax 
         FROM reservations r, sgl_table sg 
         WHERE r.tourstart = sg.tourstart
         AND r.tourbk_id = sg.tour_id"; 
$tourresult = $db->query($tourquery);} 

elseif ($row['roomtype1']) = `DBL`) {
$tourquery = "SELECT db.roomprice, r.totpax 
         FROM reservations r, dbl_table db 
         WHERE t.tourstart = db.tourstart
         AND r.tour_id = db.tour_id"; 
$tourresult = $db->query($tourquery);}
```

and so on...

Is such a possibility?  Is this syntax correct?

Also, should I use ` or ' in the php code to select the row value (SGL, DBL, TPL, QUD) of roomtype1 (assuming such is a possibility)?

Comment: No, the syntax of your boolean conditions isn't correct, the comparison operator is `==` and not `=`, which is the assignment operator. Change `if($row['roomtype1']) = \`SGL\`)` to `if($row['roomtype1'] == 'SGL'`, respectivly `($row['roomtype1']) = \`DBL\`)` to `($row['roomtype1']) == 'DBL')`. Also use `'` or `"` for PHP strings, the use of `\`` for strings is illegal in PHP.